# Understanding findAll in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Consider the following code:

```
String emptyString = '''

        '''
println "After trimming empty string has size: " + emptyString.trim().size()
println "Number of non empty elements in array: " + ([emptyString, 'kshitiz'].findAll({ it.trim() != 0}).size())
```

I expect the output to be `1`. However the output is:

```
After trimming empty string has size: 0
Number of non empty elements in array: 2
```

I suspect that I may be missing something basic here but can't quite figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
 String emptyString = '''

    '''
 println "After trimming empty string has size: " + emptyString.trim().size()
 println "Number of non empty elements in array: " + ([emptyString, 'kshitiz'].findAll({ it.trim().length() != 0}).size())
```

Notice the use of the length() method. You were not comparing the length of the string.

Comment: Damn. I knew it was something simple. Time to sleep a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The expression in the closure `{it.trim() != 0}` returns true for both list entries regardless of if the string returned by it.trim() is empty or not, so findAll doesn't filter anything out and the size of the list returned by findAll is 2.

Fixes like `{it.trim().length() != 0}` or `{it.trim() != ''}` (which you can do in Groovy since `==` uses the equals method) will work but are not necessary. Groovy treats empty (zero-length) strings as false and non-empty strings as true, see [these examples from groovy-lang.org](http://www.groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_strings):

```
assert 'a'
assert !''
def nonEmpty = 'a'
assert "$nonEmpty"
def empty = ''
assert !"$empty"
```

Removing the counterproductive `!= 0` gives

```
['', ' ', 'asdf'].findAll { it.trim() }.size()
```

which evaluates to 1, having successfully filtered out empty entries.